# Orthogonal perspective in vertex shader, origin lower left

Tags: opengl, orthographic

I'm trying to display my scene with an orthogonal projection, with position 0,0 in the lower left corner of the screen. So far I have gotten an orthogonal projection to work, but when I've tried to move the origin (with glViewport) I only get a quarter of the screen rendering.

Here's my code

http://pastebin.com/BUSuy9fs

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why did you put your code on Pastebin?

Comment: It felt kinda long to just post in the question